# Reverse current with Peltier (TEC)

Tags: peltier

Trying to control a Peltier to cool and to heat.

Does the following code allow me to reverse the current to switch cooling/heating depending on whether I input "a" or "z"?

Source: http://garagelab.com/profiles/blogs/how-to-use-a-peltier-with-arduino

```
int peltier = 3; //The N-Channel MOSFET is on digital pin 3
int power = 0; //Power level fro 0 to 99%
int peltier_level = map(power, 0, 99, 0, 255); //This is a value from 0 to 255 that actually controls the MOSFET

void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600);

//pinMode(peltier, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
char option;

if(Serial.available() > 0)
{
option = Serial.read();
if(option == 'a') 
    power += 5;
else if(option == 'z')
    power -= 5;

if(power > 99) power = 99;
if(power < 0) power = 0;

peltier_level = map(power, 0, 99, 0, 255);
}

Serial.print("Power=");
Serial.print(power);
Serial.print(" PLevel=");
Serial.println(peltier_level);

analogWrite(peltier, peltier_level); //Write this new value out to the port

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the circuit does not contain a [full bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_bridge).

[image]

Think of the TEC being L1 in the image. To make the TEC switch from one side cooling to that same side heating current needs to flow in the opposite direction through the TEC. One direction would be Q1 and Q4 ON and the other two transistors OFF. To switch current directions turn Q2 and Q3 ON and the other two OFF.

Since this circuit only contains one transistor the TEC cannot have its current direction reversed. It looks like your code will just shut off the current altogether.

Comment: Thanks! So can I achieve an H-bridge using two Mosfets? I apologize.. I don't have much circuitry experience - what other components would I need in addition to a 10k resistor and 1 mosfet?

Comment: Even with two MOSFETs you won't be able to do it. That is what is known as a half bridge. You will need 4 like in the circuit above. The arduino can drive the low side FETs, but you will need additionally circuitry to drive the upper FETs, Q1 and Q3. Alternately you could look into a full Hbridge IC.

Comment: Having trouble reading the datasheet for my MOSFET: http://www.vishay.com/docs/91328/91328.pdf

Which legs correspond to the base, collector, and emitter? Does gate=base, source=collector, and drain=emitter?

Comment: Well, if the names are different, it's also because the behavior is different. If you don't get this and also don't understand why your Arduino won't be able to drive the high side one. You should post another question with your proposed circuit before actually doing it. If you really need a kind of match: gate=base source=emitter drain=collector. But because they don't work using the same principle, this doesn't make much sens.